# share variables by PHP, python, bash

Tags: php, python, bash, variables, share

I have project that uses same initial variables on same server by different programming languages. they are PHP, python and bash. i need all languages to access those variable and I cannot exclude any language.

for now I keep 3 places to store variables: 
for php I have Mysql storage, for python and bash 2 separate files

if initial value of any variable changes, i need to change it at 3 locations

i want to simplify that now. lest assume all systems can access Mysql. is there the way define initial variables in  Mysql instead of files? or what is the best practice to share variables in my case?

Comment: You can't share variables, you can share __data__

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the best approach for me here would be to limit variable storages from 3 to at least 2 and make python script deal with bash tasks over os.system. To use 2 storages is somehow manageable